# Check if a column contains data from another column in python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, contains

I have a dataframe in pandas like this

```
name     url
pau lola www.paulola.com
pou gine www.cheeseham.com
pete raj www.pataraj.com
```

And I want to check if any of the strings in the column name are in the column url (so ignoring spaces). So something like this

```
name     url                result
pau lola www.paulola.com    True
pou gine www.cheeseham.com  False
pete raj www.pataraj.com    True
```

Is there any way to do it? I've tried to do with this lambda function but only works if contains both

```
name     url               namewospaces
pau lola www.paulola.com   paulola
pou gine www.cheeseham.com pougine
pete raj www.pataraj.com   peteraj

df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x.namewospaces) in str(x.url), axis=1)

name     url               namewospaces  result
pau lola www.paulola.com   paulola       True
pou gine www.cheeseham.com pougine       False
pete raj www.pataraj.com   peteraj       False
```

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the name into substrings, and use a list comprehension with `any` to get True is any string matches:

```
df['result'] = [any(s in url for s in lst)
                for lst, url in zip(df['name'].str.split(), df['url'])]
```

the (slower) equivalent with `apply` would be:

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: any(s in x['url']
                        for s in x['name'].split()), axis=1)
```

output:

```
       name                url  result
0  pau lola    www.paulola.com    True
1  pou gine  www.cheeseham.com   False
2  pete raj    www.pataraj.com    True
```